# Can a C# Application be both a WebSocket Client and Sever?

Tags: c#, websocket

Ok, so I am a newbie with WebSockets, but I am creating a program which can be installed on a several of my home PCs to synchronize data and program state information.

After doing some preliminary research, I am thinking that WebSockets are the best route.

The problem I seem to be running into is that all the code samples I have found have separate Server and Client applications, and this makes sense in the context of the web, but in my situation I actually do not want a dedicated server (primarily because I don't want to have a "on all the time" instance, as this is an "OnDemand" program), I'd prefer the applications to be both Client and Server.

Can someone give me some insight into how this works? I assume it is possible to be both a client and server, do I just have a Client and Server object? Can the servers be the same port across all PCs?

Comment: Yes. PADDING REQUESTED BY SO.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - OP seems to want peer<>peer across several boxes.

Comment: @MartinJames: Jees. Nice avatar, BTW :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko - I always hated vi, now I've extended the hate to vim:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you can have multiple servers, (listening on different ports), and clients in one app, if you want.

The servers can be on the same port on all you boxes 'cos they all have a different IP.

Comment: Ok, so if every app is at a different IP address, I can have every instance of the app on the same port?

I.E: Lets say the App is called InfoExchanger.
Lets say I have InfoExchanger running on PC A with a server on Port 1234 and a client AND InfoExchanger running on PC B with a server on Port 1234 and a client.

In this scenario, InfoExchanger on PC A and InfoExhanger on PC B can share information with eachother?

Comment: @Gauss - sure.  The client on A could connect to the server at BIP:1234, or the client on B could connect to the server at AIP:1234, or both could happen.  You only really need one server<>client connection to transfer data both ways, but you could use the two, if you wish.

Comment: @Gauss - I do this kind of thing often, to test my server and client apps on multiple OS.  I have XP, Vista and W7 boxes round my house/office and I run an instance of the server app on each of them, all using the same listening port.  A laptop runs 15 client instances, in three groups of five, each group connected to a different server, sending in data continually. Works fine, (well, the networking does anyway, obviously I have all my other bugs...).

Comment: Ok, Well this is helpful... Let me ask you though, how would it work if I want the first instance of the application to be the server and all subsequent ones to be the client (because I presume you can't have all servers)? How would I do that discovery (because I would like to have them self-automate their startups and not have to start A then B)? Or are we at a point where it would be easier for me to just have a dedicate server program and all my InfoExchangers be clients?

Comment: And I am not necessarily asking you to write the program for me, I just don't even know where to look for examples or documentation on what I need. Or if you had some insight into what I shouldn't do or advice on the direction I should pursue, that'd be equally as helpful.

Comment: Heh - I'll leave the network topography up to you.  No reason why they should not all have servers, but you will have to find a way of managing all the connections.  If BitTorrent can do it, you should be able to:)